# Get AES_DECRYPT Value From "MySQL" in ASP.NET webPage

Tags: mysql, asp.net, passwords, aes

My "MySQL Connection" is perfectly working in ASP.NET

I can get and insert value in database perfectly

The Problem Occurs when I want to get a Password value from the following Table

```
The Table has columns as,
ID->Integer
name->Varchar
mobile_no->VarChar
password->blob

Password column gives me problem

    MySqlCommand cmd2=new MySqlCommand("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password,'qwerty') FROM mytable1 where mobile_no=@z2", connection);

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z2", TextBox1.Text);

    String pass = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


The 3rd line is giving me problem.

I want to compare this "pass" with ""Textbox2.text""

OR

I want to display that password on webpage (just fro try)

i.e., ""Label1.text=pass""

Its displaying this on Label...... ""System.Byte[] ""
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
  MySqlCommand cmd2=new MySqlCommand("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password,'qwerty') FROM mytable1 where mobile_no=@z2", connection);

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z2", TextBox1.Text);

        //prepare adapter to run query
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        //get query results in DataTable
        adapter.Fill(Dt);
string pass = Dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
     // your password contains Byte array as You said it is showing System.Byte[]
//You should convert it /Decode it into proper Plain text
```

**EDIT**
Depending On Your Encoding You can try like this

```
string  result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(pass);

string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pass);

//dispaly result on label
```

Comment: I have created every required connection, adapter and everything else required....

i have just cut my code in short....

but if i follow exact your code......then also....

"pass" will contain "System.Byte[] " and not the original passowrd

Comment: Not Helpful Bro


string pass = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();


string result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(pass);


string result2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pass);
                

Label1.Text = result;


The Encoding lines are giving error, "Invalid Arguement"

The Arguement should of type byte[]


but mine arguement is "System.Byte[] "

Comment: dont use both at a time use 1st one or 2nd one Default or UTF8

Comment: buddy i am using only 1 at a time and its not allowing me to run the page, it showing compilation error, .i.e., red colored underline...what will be the datatype of value at dt.rows[0][0]....if its value in database is "blob" ?

Comment: @AvtarSingh A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable **LARGE** amount of data.It is non readable to Human Being something like this `3E53831E-9BDD-498C-A157-5B90830F6857`.You Should Know proper Encoding For Your Byte Array to convert it in plain Text

Comment: yes i thought as same u said....but now....how would i know proper encoding for ma Byte Array to convert it in plain text ? :(....its simple thing......theres a datatype blob in mysql.....we want to retrieve its value from database to label in asp.net

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=PlMxVOapFOPV8gfwpoC4Bg&gws_rd=ssl#q=online+tool+to+convert+byte[]++to+string